# Duplicate keys in python dictionary

Tags: python

I read this in the official documentation of Python

> It is best to think of a dictionary as a set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary).

But when I am running this code

```
dic={"a":1,"b":2,"a":3,"a":2,"a":4,"a":5}
print(dic["a"])
```

I'm always getting 5 as output. I want to know why.

Comment: Just a guess: It evaluates the pairs in sequence, so you're constantly overwriting "a"'s value

Comment: And this does not contradict with that documentation: the dict is required to keep only unique keys, so it decides to keep the last pair only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a dict literal (within `{}`) and a key occurs multiple times, the last one "overwrites" the previous ones. It's just the decision that was taken in the first versions of Python.

Print the whole dict to see:

```
>>> dic={"a":1,"b":2,"a":3,"a":2,"a":4,"a":5}
>>> dic
{'a': 5, 'b': 2}
```

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), emphasis mine:

> If a comma-separated sequence of key/datum pairs is given, they are
>   evaluated from left to right to define the entries of the dictionary:
>   each key object is used as a key into the dictionary to store the
>   corresponding datum. **This means that you can specify the same key**
>   **multiple times in the key/datum list, and the final dictionary’s value**
>   **for that key will be the last one given.**

Answer (score 1):

You just answered it in your quote from documentation - keys are unique, so "a" keeps getting re-assigned - and holds only last value - that's 5 in your case